# Simple ssembly program segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, arm

Iam beginner in assembly language, can any one explain what is wrong with my simple code and fix it?

Iam trying to read integer number and display it, my program is as follow:

```
.data
.global main
.extern printf
main:
    mov r1, #20 //read value 20 into register r1
    bl printf   //print the value
```

but why it seems not working ?!

Comment: `printf` expects as its first argument the address of a format string which tells it how to interpret the rest of the arguments. Also, you seem to be missing a call to `exit` or some other code that will terminate your program in a proper way.

Comment: @Michael can you fix it please cuz I really dont know how thanks

Comment: @Michael does this code correct based on what you said ?
.data      
   string: .asciz "%d\n"        
.text
.global main
.extern printf

main:
    push    {ip, lr}        
                            
    ldr     r0, =string     
    mov     r1, #32
    bl      printf          

    pop     {ip, pc}